# Is using a reference to a derived class member in its base class well defined in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, undefined-behavior

I was looking into some code and it seemed to work but I am not sure if it is defined behavior.

I think there is a problem in it because Base is constructed with a reference to a Derived member variable - which is in my understanding constructed after Base.

I did some research on this and all I found were answers stating that Base is constructed before Derived, and Arguments from a Derived Constructor can be forwarded to the Base constructor.

But what about Derived Members, can they safely be forwarded to a Base Constructor?
Might Constructor and Destructor or even Member-Functions in Base work with invalid objects?

Here is simple code sample with the problem:

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base(SomeClass & obj): m_obj(obj)
   {
       // Does using m_obj here cause problems with a Derived instance?
   }

   virtual ~Base()
   {
       // Does using m_obj here cause problems with a Derived instance?
   }
   
   void SomeMethod()
   {
       // Does using m_obj here cause problems with a Derived instance?
   }
   
private:
   SomeClass & m_obj;
};


class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():Base(m_derObj){}

private:
    SomeClass m_derObj{123};
};
```

[OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/-6sJDNwgC)

Maybe I am missing some guarantee C++ gives - or maybe we were just lucky and the error never occurred.

Comment: Besides the error in `SomeClass m_derObj(123);` (which is an invalid member function declaration) it's fine.

Comment: Sorry for that - fixed it and added a Link to OnlineGDB, it compiles.
Thanks for the fast answer, but maybe you can help me out why this is not a problem, for me it still seems like SomeClass is constructed after the Base-Constructor runs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When the reference `Base::m_obj` is initialized, the referenced object `Derived::m_derObj` has not yet been initialized, right? Is it ok to create a reference to a not-yet initialized object (basically to its storage)?

Comment: @DanielLangr It hasn't been initialized, but it exists and one can create references to it. As long as the object isn't used in any other way then it's all well and fine.

Comment: @mile4712 The `Base` constructor can initialize the `m_obj` member, but the constructor body can't use the referenced object as it haven't been initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using a reference to a derived class member in its base class well defined in C++?

Yes.

> ```
> SomeClass m_derObj(123);
> ```

This is invalid syntax. If you intended to write a default member initialiser, you must use either curly braces or equals initialiser.

> ```
> Base(SomeClass & obj): m_obj(obj)
> {
>     // Does using m_obj here cause problems with a Derived instance?
> }
> ```

The referred object hasn't been initialised yet, so you are very limited in what you can do with the reference.

If you try to do something that isn't allowed for such reference, such as for example try to access the referred object, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. If you don't do such thing, then it's OK.

> ```
> virtual ~Base()
> {
>     // Does using m_obj here cause problems with a Derived instance?
> }
> ```

The referred object has been destroyed already, so you are very limited in what you can do with the reference.

If you try to do something that isn't allowed for such reference, such as for example try to access the referred object, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. If you don't do such thing, then it's OK.

> ```
> void SomeMethod()
> {
>     // Does using m_obj here cause problems with a Derived instance?
> }
> ```

Depending on which constructor you used to initialise the object, there is a possibility that the reference has become dangling. In such case, there won't be anything that you can do with the reference without causing undefined behaviour. Furthermore, if you call the function from the constructor or destructor, the issue with the object being destroyed/not yet constructed applies.

But in the case the reference is still valid, it's fine.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the syntax error in the original code now.
How could the reference be dangling in the last case with the method?

Comment: @mile4712 The referred object may have been destroyed.

Comment: Ok, I can think of cases where this does happen but only in multithreaded environments or if the method is called in the destructor or am I wrong?

Comment: @mile4712 Think about what happens when you use the copy constructor. What object does the copy refer to? What happens when the original is destroyed? Answer: Dangling reference happens.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your hunch is correct.

Using an object before it has been constructed, or after it has been destroyed, has undefined behaviour, and the worst type of undefined behaviour is the appearance of working properly.
(You can't conclude from watching a C++ program do what it's supposed to do that it doesn't have undefined behaviour.)

The constructor can store the reference but not use the referred object in any way, since that object's lifetime hasn't started yet.

The destructor can't use the object since its lifetime has already ended.

You can use the referred object in other member functions during its lifetime in the regular way.

This lifetime issue is Yet Another Reason to avoid references as members.